# Set Hadoop User in sqoop command

Tags: sqoop

I want to run a sqoop command as a different user. I can set HADOOP_USER_NAME command before I run the sqoop job like this:

```
export HADOOP_USER_NAME=desiredUser

sqoop import \
-D mapreduce.map.memory.mb=4096 \
-D mapreduce.map.java.opts=-Xmx3200m \
--driver ...\
--connect ..\
--username ..
```

I was wondering If there is a way to set this in the sqoop command similar to how I set mapreduce.map.memory.mb option. I tried

```
...
-D HADOOP_USER_NAME=desiredUser
...
```

but it didn't changed the user.
Thanks for any reply

Answer (score 1):

There is no such option using `-D` for user. `-D` are being used to supply mapreduce property. But you can try using `sudo` command. Using `sudo` Sqoop command will be `sudo HADOOP_USER_NAME=desiredUser sqoop import <generic args>`

Comment: As per @Sandeep Singh answer it's working perfect. example : HADOOP_USER_NAME=UserName sqoop export  --connect 'jdbc:mysql: XXX remain arguments **

Answer (score 0):

You can simply do it in the Unix by Su to other user and run the sqoop command. Refer the Following example :

```
su somebody <<    'EOF'command1 -p 'parameter with “quotes" inline' EOF
```

You can run the multiple commands with `command2 -p 'parameter with "quotes" inline'` between the EOFs.

To be specific for your sqoop job, if you have the access to some user use the command `Su - yourUser “sqoop command”`

If you are sudoing use this

```
sudo -H -u otheruser bash -c 'echo "I am $USER, with uid $UID"' 


man sudo will be your guru to explore more options
```

Comment: Unfortunately for various reasons I want to avoid using sudo. I am really interested if the user can change as a sqoop argument not as Linux option